# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when return promise in nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, promise

There was an application error recently when during the `dBWrapper.queryUserFriends` call... I tried to hit a table that doesn't exist in the database. That is all resolved and made sense but I also get the following warning that I can't figure out why. I tried to add a catch to all the asynchronous calls as well but that didn't help

Getting the following warning from nodejs:

> (node:7741) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection (node:7741) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
> are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
> will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. */

```
router.get("/getUserDetails", function(req, res) {
    doesUserExist(User)
        .then(id => getUserData(id))
        .then(userData => res.json(userData))
        .catch(error => res.json({
            'error': error
        }));
});



function getUserData(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dBWrapper.queryUserDetails(id)
            .then(async function(data) {
                for (x in data) {
                    await dBWrapper.queryUserFriends(data)
                        .then(function(result) {
                            // <------ where the error happens 
                        })
                }
                resolve(data)
            });
    });
}

function queryUserDetails(id) {
    let query = 'SELECT * from User where User.id =' + id;
    return processQuery(query);
}

function queryUserFriends(id) {
    let query = 'SELECT * from Friends where User.id =' + id;
    return processQuery(query);
}

function processQuery(query) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let connection;

            db
            .getConnection()
            .then(function(c) {
                connection = c;
                    return connection.execute(query);
            })
            .then(
                function(result) {
                    resolve(result.rows);
                },
                function(err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
            )
            .then(function() {
                if (connection) {
                    return connection.close();
                }
            })

    });
}
```

Comment: Just return the `queryUserDetails` Promise itself and it'll be chained with the caller of `getUserData` properly

Comment: @CertainPerformance isn't that what I am doing right now?

Comment: No, you're wrapping it in a new constructed Promise for some reason

Comment: @CertainPerformance so I can remove the new constructed Promise and return dBWrapper.queryUserDetails(id).then()?

Comment: Yes, see the linked canonical